# how to setup more than offer Buy 2 Get 1 free in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog-price-rules

I setup Buy 2 Get 1 free offer in magento. it's working fine. But I setup morethan one in same way it's not working?

Can you tell me any one how it is?

and how to setup if cellphone purchase! memory card free?

thanks in advance...........

Comment: How have you tried to set-up these rules?

Comment: Can you please add the rules you configured, what you expect, what you tried and what doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Real buy X get Y free, where X and Y are different SKUs is not available in magento without custom extension.

There are a few at the magento connect or you can build you own, that extends default shopping cart rule functionality. See http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table